# Privately hosted chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, private, hosted

Does anyone has able to create a Chrome extension and host it Privately? not within Chrome web store.

i was trying to achieve full CI-CD for one of our chrome extensions and seems like when publishing the extension it is pending for manual review from google side, and this can take up to days.

So, i've started to see if i can host this extension on some private web store, and found few places on the web that indicate it is possible in a way.

I've uploaded my crx along with a manifest.xml to some public location and tried to add this extension using customURL on the Google Admin Console.

The extension was added and i see it on the list of the Admin Console (apps & extensions view). I've configured it with 'Allow to install' but when trying to install it on my laptop i still see it disabled with the warning "This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge."

Do i have to enforce Devices Enrolment to achieve this ?

any idea?
thanks

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, i saw this, tried that, it doesnt work either. it also mentioned there that for mac you cannot install from non web store location